# Orchestra not in tune? (not working out of the box)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, catel, orchestra

I am trying to use Orchestra.

I first try to use the template from the git repository (Orchestra.Shell.zip from https://github.com/Orcomp/Orchestra/tree/develop/templates/C%23).

After I install Orchestra.Shell from nuget, I see that the installed components requested are >= 3.3. In reality, it downloads 3.3 which results in the following errors:

> Error 1   'Catel.Windows.Controls.UserControl' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultCreateWarningAndErrorValidatorForViewModelValue' D:\Projects\OrchestraShell1\OrchestraShell1\App.xaml.cs 25  48  OrchestraShell1
>
> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'ModelBase' does not exist in the namespace 'Catel.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    D:\Projects\Tests\OrchestraShell1\OrchestraShell1\App.xaml.cs   27  24  OrchestraShell1
>
> Error 3   'Catel.IoC.ServiceLocator' does not contain a definition for 'Default'  D:\Documents\OrchestraShell1\App.xaml.cs    29  49  OrchestraShell1

I tried to updating to latest Catel libraries

> update-package catel.mvvm

The project compile successfully but then when I try to run it I get a type load exception:

> Method 'add_ViewLoading' in type 'Orchestra.Views.MainWindow' from assembly 'Orchestra.Shell, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

Next, after smoothing it a little and following some pointers from here:

http://webpixel.gr/projects/worchestra/?p=20

I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Fluent, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e436e32a8c5546f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This can be fixed by installing fluent.ribbon package but still I am getting same error.

I tried to add a module as describe in http://webpixel.gr/projects/worchestra/?p=23 but that didn't help either.

Is this thing supposed to work? Am I missing anything or have done something wrong? Do I need to develop a module for the shell to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out the new notes at the readme:

https://github.com/orcomp/orchestra#update-20140817

We are working on better version (v2). Please check out the examples (we provide 1 example for each shell type). You can pick one of the following assemblies:

1. Orchestra.Shell.MahApps => metro interface
2. Orchestra.Shell.Ribbon.Microsoft => office a-like with ms ribbon
3. Orchestra.Shell.TaskRunner => run tasks easily (you probably don't
   need this one)

Comment: Thanks. How stable are these? Would you recommend it for production?

Comment: We use them in several production apps, so very stable.